# How to tell TypeScript: this generic type must be a string?

Tags: typescript

Inside a class, one of its property is an indexable object. I need to index that object with a string that I want to restrict to few options only.

But I want the options to be different for each instance of that class.
Here is the [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKD2BrApgW3gOwDwBVrIA8AXZDAExgiICcBLDAcwD4BvAWAChpoAHMasKgBc0FtADatMiJwBdEWAwBPaAF9oAXlHqA9DugAJeAHdoReNDAA3eFLMALWjGTVq8ap07cGyIrH6CABR8AqgAktLQOACUol7c0NS%20AK7UGA5OAHQhguI54WSy0HqGJmYW1rZkGc6u7vGqnhyNHHoAogRoPCDI0ACMnERKPL0A8soE-qEwWgDkECPIZLPQAD7Q8zSkDPYrnMCYVNCYSgSa0BjIpggo6Njjp1OCEEyB0ZwnBJk%20fgGogfNFst3hxPt9fE9-ptBPQwLNYu06tRoPYXL0IPZ4MkQNUAEa9DDuVBgEBNdqdVDdXoAJkGw16sFoiDAwHsyUhMw2VBhGDhaw2YAYtBAtCGs32hyIvCZLLZ50u1yQaEwWEZzNZ7L%20LzenB4Mo14N%20oQBguFoqU8N1%20rZhshAKoSUYuwROjaSJRaOgGKxOOg%20IuRJJnCAA) I tried:

```
class Pokemon<T extends string>{
  param: { [id: T]: any } = {} // An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'

  getParam(paramId: T) {
    return this.param[paramId] // Type 'T' cannot be used to index type '{}'
  }

}
//Exemple 1
type OnyxParams = 'speed' | 'strengh' 
const onyx = new Pokemon<OnyxParams>()
onyx.getParam('speed')
onyx.getParam('stamina') //Error here should be normal

//Exemple 2
type PikachuParams = 'stamina' | 'agility'
const pikachu = new Pokemon<PikachuParams>()
pikachu.getParam('agility')
pikachu.getParam('strengh') //Error here should be normal
```

I am getting two errors
 `Type 'T' cannot be used to index type '{}'`
 and `An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'`

From What I understand, Typescript is telling me that `T` must be a either a string or number because I am using it as index. That makes sense. So how do I tell Typescript that yes, T should be a string or a number otherwise, throw an error what I try to set something else here :

```
const pikachu = new Pokemon<SomethingNotStringOrNumber>()
```

What should I edit on the above code? 
I already searched and I found that `T extends string` instead of `T` whould restrict it but this does not remove the two errors.

Comment: You want `[id in T]` instead of `[id: T]`.

Comment: It fixes one but creates a new error: `Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ [id in T]: any; }'.`

Comment: Well, it isn't assignable; you said the object should have those properties from `T`, and it doesn't. You can do `{ [id in T]?: any }` to make them optional properties.

Answer (score 0):

First of all string is a primitive value you can not extend from primitives String by the other hand is the Object.

If you know that what ever your getting is a string why not setting it as string in the first place

```js
class MyClass<T=string> {}
```

If by any means you are getting a number from who knows where 
`class MyClass<T=string | number> {}`